Jupyter Notebooks in VS Code No Longer Recognize Working Directory—Why?
Starting this week, my Jupyter notebooks in VS Code have stopped recognizing the working directory correctly. Previously, everything worked as expected without any manual configuration.
When I run a Python script in a new interactive window or initiate a new Jupyter notebook and execute pwd, it outputs my home directory instead of the script's directory. This behavior disrupts my ability to import other modules located in the same directory. I haven't made any recent changes to my setup that could have triggered this issue (maybe background updates?).
As a temporary workaround, I manually change the current working directory in my scripts, but this approach is inconvenient. I'm looking for a solution that rather identifies/fixes that issue.
Has anyone else experienced this issue recently?
Could there be a problem with the latest versions of VS Code or its Python/Jupyter extensions?
Does anyone have a solution that doesn't involve modifying every script to manually set the working directory?
Thank you for your assistance!

"maybe background updates?" - You might have VSC and/or VSC extensions set to auto-update.

I can't reproduce the problem in a Codespace using VSCode 1.90.0-insider, Jupyter v2024.4.2024042601. What versions are you using? Could the problem actually be in your IPykernel config? (for example, maybe it runs %cd somewhere.) And just to make sure, what does ?pwd say?

Here are my versions: Python extension v2024.6.0, Jupyter extension v2024.4.0 and VS Code is 1.89.1 dc96b837cf6bb4af9cd736aa3af08cf8279f7685 x64. ?pwd gives: Docstring:
Return the current working directory path.
Examples
::
In [9]: pwd
Out[9]: '/home/tsuser/sprint/ipython'
File:      /opt/Anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/osm.py

Where is the kernel version you are using? My machine doesn't have a problem showing your workspace file structure and basic examples.

Thank you for your answer. My kernel is: 3.10.0-1160.95.1.el7.x86_64

This seems to be an unrepeatable case, you can provide the developer with a log on github and see how to fix it.
